# Does Solr facet return only count?

Tags: solr, facet

I wanted to group results based on a field in solr and get the group count and the documents at once, but facet is returning only the count.
Tried group=true as well but that doesn't return total group count.Is there any way to do it in solr ?

Any input would be helpful

Edit:

solrQuery.setParam("group.field", "memberId"); I have used something like this in the query and
Query results for groupResponse is  this

```
grouped": {
    "memberId": {
      "matches": 14,
      "groups": [
        {
          "groupValue": "179035",
                    "doclist": {
                      "numFound": 1,
                      "start": 0,
                      "docs": [
                        "memberId":179035
                            ]
                    }
        },
        {
          "groupValue": "179039",
                    "doclist": {
                      "numFound": 1,
                      "start": 0,
                      "docs": [
                        "memberId":179035
                            ]
                    }
        },
        {
          "groupValue": "179040",
                    "doclist": {
                      "numFound": 1,
                      "start": 0,
                      "docs": [
                        "memberId":179035
                            ]
                    }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But I need the group count that is 3 here along with the grouped documents.
The numfound & matches here is giving the count of all records without the group

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're looking for? `numFound` should be the total group count when using grouping, iirc?

Comment: @MatsLindh I've Edited the question with an example

Comment: Did you try adding `group.ngroups`? If true, Solr includes the number of groups that have matched the query in the results. https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/result-grouping.html#grouping-parameters

Comment: remove field names from fl to bring all fields. group.ngroups can give u number of groups and you can get those all records by putting it in rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the total number of groups, add the `group.ngroups` parameter:

> `group.ngroups`: If true, Solr includes the number of groups that have matched the query in the results.